# Delphi 7 idHTTP JSON Data Null Result

Tags: php, mysql, json, delphi, indy

Main goal is send all data to remote mysql database. 
I'm using TidHTTP for POST method. Having nearly 10.000 records, around 2MB data. When I run delphi codes, upload json data. But some records doesn't insert.

**Delphi Codes:**

```
function TFrmUploadDataWithJSON.PostJS(JS: string): string;
var
  lStream: TStringStream;
  parameters: TStringList;

begin
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  lStream := TStringStream.Create(Result);
  try
    Parameters := TStringList.Create;
    parameters.Add('js=' + JS);
    IdHTTP1.Post('http://domain.com/uploadi.php', parameters,lStream);
    lStream.Position := 0;
    Result := lStream.ReadString(lStream.Size);
  finally
    //FreeAndNil(lHTTP);
    FreeAndNil(lStream);
  end;
end;
```

**Update 1: PHP Side**
After these update I'm getting "not parsed" response. About 2.5 MB is big data for JSON Parse?

Here codes:

```
<?php
  include_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/DBConnect.php';

  function update($json){    
    $db = new DbConnect();

    $response = array();
    $res=array();

    if($json!=null){
      $done = 0;
      $fail = 0;

      $mErr = "";

      $decoded=json_decode($json,true);

      //$decode= var_dump($decoded);
      //$ss=$decode["array"];
      //echo $decoded['number'];
      if(is_array($decoded["items"]))
      {
        foreach($decoded["items"] as $items)
        {
          $a=$items["a"];
          $b=$items["b"];

          mysql_query("delete from `items` where `code` = '$a'") or $mErr = $mErr ."-". mysql_error();        
          //header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);

          $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO items (`code`, `numune_id`) VALUES ('$a', '$b')";

          $result = mysql_query($sqlstr) or  $mErr = $mErr ."-". mysql_error();
          if ($result) {
            $done = $done + 1;
          } else {
            $fail = $fail + 1;
          }
        }

        $response["done"] = $done;
        $response["fail"] = $fail;
        $response["mysql errors"] =  $mErr;
        if ($fail > 0) 
          $response["error"] = "must be repost";

      } else {
        $response["error"] = "json not parsed";
      }
    } else {      
      $response["error"] = "json not posted";

    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
  }


    update($_POST["js"]);

?>
```

**Update 2: Delphi Side**
I changed ContentType as "**application/json**". And get json data throught RAW Data. But still json data doesn't decode.

```
function PostJS(AFormat, JS: string): string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RBody: TStringStream;
  params: TStringList;

begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(self);
  RBody := TStringStream.Create(Result);

  IdHTTP.OnWork := IdHTTP1Work;
  IdHTTP.OnWorkBegin := IdHTTP1WorkBegin;
  IdHTTP.OnWorkEnd := IdHTTP1WorkEnd;

  try
    Params := TStringList.Create;
    params.Add('js=' + JS);
    params.Add('command=a1b234lTrLKMDEk');

    if AFormat = 'json' then
    begin
      IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/javascript';
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
    end
    else
    begin
      IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/xml';
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'text/xml';
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentEncoding := 'utf-8';
    end;

    IdHTTP.Post('http://domain.com/upload.php',params, RBody);

    RBody.Position := 0;
    Result := RBody.ReadString(RBody.Size);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(RBody);
    FreeAndNil(IdHTTP);
  end;
end;
```

**PHP Side:**
I think I'm right way. **json_last_error()** is giving me why doesn't decoded it.

```
<?php
  include_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/DBConnect.php';

  function update($json){    

    $db = new DbConnect();

    $response = array();
    $res=array();

    if($json!=null){
      $done = 0;
      $fail = 0; 

      $mErr = "";

      $decoded=json_decode($json,true);

      if(is_array($decoded["items"]))
      {
        foreach($decoded["items"] as $items)
        {
          $a=$items["a"];
          $b=$items["b"];


          mysql_query("delete from `items` where `code` = '$a'") or $mErr = $mErr ."-". mysql_error();        

          $sqlstr = "INSERT INTO items (`code`, `numune_id`) VALUES ('$a', '$b')";

          $result = mysql_query($sqlstr) or  $mErr = $mErr ."-". mysql_error();
          if ($result) {
            $done = $done + 1;
          } else {
            $fail = $fail + 1;
          }
        }

        $response["done"] = $done;
        $response["fail"] = $fail;
        $response["mysql err"] =  $mErr;
        if ($fail > 0) 
          $response["error"] = "must be repost";

      } else {

        $response["error"] = "json not parsed";
        switch (json_last_error()) {
            case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
                $e1= ' - No errors';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                $e1= ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
                $e1= ' - Underflow or the modes mismatch';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                $e1= ' - Unexpected control character found';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                $e1= ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
            break;
            case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:
                $e1= ' - Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded';
            break;
            default:
                $e1= ' - Unknown error';
            break;
        }
        $response["message"] =$e1;
        $response["json"] = $json;
      }
    } else {       
      $response["error"] = "json not posted";

    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
  }

  parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$post_vars);

  if ($post_vars["command"] == 'a1b234lTrLKMDEk') {
    update($post_vars["js"]);
  } 
?>
```

**I found the reason. Simply tye reason is indy components version. **
I upgrade my codes to Delphi xe7 and now It's ok now.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are all records inserted or not? And what exactly is the question?

Comment: All records not inserted. I checked with $done and $fail variables. All done but when I check mysql table some records doesn't inserted. There are 10455 records delphi side. But after run there are about 9500 records in mysql table. I cant find where they gone. I think php there are problem in php side.

Comment: Your code does not write error messages if the JSON can not be parsed - there is no else after in `if($json!=null){ $decoded=json_decode($json,true);  if(is_array($decoded["items"])) `...

Comment: weird structure you create... `json[i].A['items'].Add(json_sub);` you make 15000 arrays containing one item, instead of making one array containing 15000 items!

Comment: using `q.RecordCount ` and `q.FieldValues['code']` is also really not an efficient code!
  http://pastebin.com/vsyjhEjR

Comment: I'm adding control of parsed or not @mjn .

Comment: I create this structure cause I tried package by package. I've declared json as an array. I tried with packages (10, 100, 250, 500 records).  My all triying is same result. Some records is missing. @Arioch'The

Comment: Why are they efficient? are they attended variables? @Arioch'The

Comment: What exactly you consider variable? RecordCount is a function that works differently for different data sources. Sometimes you just cannot know in advance how many records you have. So until it is proven you can use it with no penalty you better avoid it. // You made you packet as array of 1-item arrays rather than just an array of items. Make ten rows dataset and read the JSON source of the packet. It is weird and redundant.

Comment: Your php code lacks transactions control BTW. May it be that last batch just gets rolled back on timeout?

Comment: Ur PHP code also asks for someone taking full control of database out of your hands.       http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I confused now @Arioch'The. Understood your efficient code comment. I will check BTW. On the orher hand I now this is not secure codes. But this codes whitout security preventions. Thank you very much.

Comment: `IdHTTP1.Post('http://domain.com/uploadi.php'` - you code is using www global access - so you are just waiting for someone to start re-using your database for hosting CP or warez or anything. And even if you would do intranet-local app, you better still start with safe patterns: when later your app would be extended to work online you would not have to reconsider all the sources written years and years ago.

Comment: Now regarding your programs, I think you better to check who is in the wrong -  Delphi code or PHP code - first and then make your question narrow and detailed. Also I think you'd better ZIP your packet before sending. Not that it only would reduce and fasten the traffic, it also would protect you from "only half of the packet received" scenario.

Comment: Store the incoming JSON to a local file and use Notepad++ or a JSON validator / parser to find out where exactly is corrupted and causes the "not parsed".

Comment: It seems that you are using the wrong way to construct the HTTP request. See https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2015/03/14/indy-10-6-https-post/ for example code. The JSON will be corrupted if you use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and parameters in the body.

Comment: @mjn, when I check generated json text on validator. There are no problem validating. Also I write html form include multiline text. Json text parse and insert data to table perfectly now. But idHttp component doesn't parse clearly.

Comment: @RedLEON did you check the *incoming* JSON on the server side? Yes, the problem is the HTTP request, see my answer below.

Comment: At last I know the problem. @mjn **It give syntax error after json_decode** I get that json data. And saw them, they are missed. Not full. Trimmed last. But why. **Does TidHTTP (Delphi 7, indy version: 9.0.18) work fine? Or Do I missed one of paramaters?

Comment: At last I know the problem. @Arioch-the. **It give syntax error after json_decode** I get that json data. And saw them, they are missed. Not full. Trimmed last. But why. **Does TidHTTP (Delphi 7, indy version: 9.0.18) work fine? Or Do I missed one of paramaters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTTP client needs to use a different way to transfer the JSON data. Here is a basic example:

```
uses
  IdHTTP, IdGlobal, SysUtils, Classes;

var
  HTTP: TIdHTTP;
  RequestBody: TStream;
  ResponseBody: string;
begin
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    try
      RequestBody := TStringStream.Create('{... (JSON) ...}', // (1)
        TEncoding.UTF8); // (2)
      try
        HTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
        HTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
        ResponseBody := HTTP.Post('http://example.com/post', RequestBody);
      finally
        RequestBody.Free;
      end;
      WriteLn(ResponseBody);
      WriteLn(HTTP.ResponseText);
    except
      on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        WriteLn(E.Message);
        WriteLn(E.ErrorMessage);
      end;
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn(E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Notes:

- (1) you must not use a `TStringList` for the JSON body.  That version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` formats the data according to the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type, which is not appropriate for JSON and will corrupt it.
- (2) make sure you encode the JSON body as UTF-8.

Comment: I find similar solution a few web pages. You may be right about content type "application/json". But this time another problem come out: How can i parse and response with php? I'm using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", adding "js" parameter. And post them like a html form. In PHP side I've get JSON data with $_Post["js"] command.

Comment: @RedLEON sorry, I don't know how PHP

Comment: Thanks mjn. I will find how to do.

Comment: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the wrong format to use when posting JSON data (or any non-webform data). That format is used by the `TStrings` version of `TIdHTTP.Post()`. Posting the JSON as a `TStream` is the correct approach. The server will receive the raw JSON data as-is. PHP can access that raw data using either [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) or [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php). `$_POST` only works with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` posts.

Comment: Thx @RemyLebeau. I used `php://input` and it's work fine.